# First time creating UML diagram. I have two data structures Manager and Employee what class do they derive from?

Tags: oop, uml, object-oriented-database

So I have a class called "PERSON" then three data structures "Employees" , "Manager" and "Customer" but manager should have everything that employee has but with more capabilities but not more member variables right?

I am creating a hypothetical call center. I am trying to figure out if I should create a data structure person. Then another for staff then employee and manager  derive from there. and then another derived data structure called customer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance), This should clarify your question.

Comment: "Employees" , "Manager" are attributes as person can be both at the same time and related by "reports-to". these can be roles so that same employee object behaves as Manager or Reportee by type casting. "Customer" may have different state structure. but important point is that every Employee can be Customer but opposite is not true.